# How to scrape information off of a string of html code stored in a request url?

Tags: python

I want a list of all the donors to SLC politics along with their addresses. Instead of waiting on my open records request I just wanted to scrape it. Instead of using the original url, I used the request url, but then it opens up to a string of html code I don't know how to extract information from.

I inspected the page (https://dotnet.slcgov.com/Attorneys/CampaignFinance_Public/#/Contributors) which contains information of different donors to SLC politics. Well, apparently I can't scrape using the above url because it doesn't show anything if I don't click on any letters, so I then opened up the request url after I selected A, for example. 
So the url I got became this: https://dotnet.slcgov.com/Attorneys/CampaignFinance_Public/api/CampaignFinanceAPI/GetContributorsByStartingIndex?pIndexCharacter=A
Seems like something I can work with.
But the second url opens up to a string of plain code, a list of each donor's information as an individual item. I've never had to scrape out of this before. How do I break the code up and tell python I want each line separated and stored into a different cell? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Looks like JSON. See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html

Comment: Yes, this is a JSON, you can treat it as a very big list of (potentially nested) dictionaries i.e. if you input `my_json[0]['City']` you'll get "Salt Lake City".

Comment: Thanks y'all!! I'll take a crack at it!

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTTP GET request to fetch the data, store it in a variable.

```
req = requests.get(url = FETCHED_URL)
data = req.json()
```

This variable holds a list of dictionaries. Access each dictionary in the list by iterating it.

Comment: @Stella Yu If you find the answer helpful, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark.